# php session -> 980,000 bytes?

Tags: php, session, size

I work on a website on which I must add functionality without changing existing code.
I notice that the php session variable created on the bootstrap is almost 1 MB (980,000 bytes).
That's a lot ...
this website must be able to accommodate more than 10,000 users a day.
you find it normal?

thank you

nb:Excuse me for translation, translate it from google ...

Answer (score 2):

10 GB of RAM on a server is not that big of a deal. My current work box has more. That said, 1MB of session data *on startup* (as opposed to gradual accumulation) does sound a little extreme. Do some global search in the code - what goes into the session?

Comment: Maybe easier than searching the code would be to just see what's in the session: `file_put_contents('/web/writable/file',print_r($_SESSION,true))`

Comment: Thanks. Parts of the DB go into the session, which are then used to call webservices, which are also stored in the DB... The problem is that all these data are used in several different parts of the website: if we delete session data, the website won't work anymore.

Comment: So they use session for, essentially, database caching. Consider migrating to a better cache solution, like APC for example.